# Не понимаю как правильно прописать кнопки в телеграм боте на Python

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Как прописать кнопки для тг бота а именно key4-14, чтобы при нажатии на любую из этих кнопок он выводил next_menu3.
Сделано все там конечно колхозно

```
elif call.data == "key3":
    next_menu2 = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    key4 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Алмазарский район', callback_data='key4')
    key5 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Юнусабадский район', callback_data='key5')
    key6 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Мирзо-Улугбекский район', callback_data='key6')
    key7 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Шайхантаурский район', callback_data='key7')
    key8 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Учтепинский район', callback_data='key8')
    key9 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Чиланзарский район', callback_data='key9')
    key10 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Мирабадский район', callback_data='key10')
    key11 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Хамзинский район', callback_data='key11')
    key12 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Бектемирский район', callback_data='key12')
    key13 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Яккасарайский район', callback_data='key13')
    key14 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Сергелийский район', callback_data='key14')
    key1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Назад', callback_data='key1')
    next_menu2.add(key4, key5, key6, key7,key8,key9,key10,key11,key12,key13,key14,key1)
    bot.edit_message_text('Выберите район', call.message.chat.id, call.message.message_id,
                          reply_markup=next_menu2)
elif call.data == "key4" "key5" "key6" "key7":
    next_menu3 = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    key3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Оплата', callback_data='key3')
    back = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Назад', callback_data='mainmenu')
    next_menu3.add(key3, back)
    bot.edit_message_text('Оплатите товар', call.message.chat.id, call.message.message_id,
                          reply_markup=next_menu3)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

````
elif call.data.startswith('key') and int(call.data.replace('key', '')) in range (4, 14):
    next_menu3 = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    key3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Оплата', callback_data='key3')
    back = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Назад', callback_data='mainmenu')
    next_menu3.add(key3, back)
    bot.edit_message_text('Оплатите товар', call.message.chat.id, call.message.message_id,
                          reply_markup=next_menu3)```
````